# Populating Rails drop down via MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to populate a drop down with the values from a MongoDB table. The drop down is supposed to list the names of "sources" and the table has two columns for each "source" - "name" and "code".

Currently when I try to run my program, I receive this error -

*undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass*

I have played around with modifications here and there but to no avail. If someone could clarify my errors, that'd be much appreciated. Thanks.

Below is my code:

Model - source.rb

```
class Source
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name, type: String
 field :code, type: String
end
```

View - index.html.erb (home/landing page)

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Manage</h1>
<div class="container">
<%= form_for @home do |f| %>
 <div class="column-left">
 <h2>Sources</h2>
  <%= f.collection_select(:source_id, @sources, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select a source...") %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller - home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @sources = Source.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you have `form_for @source` and then a list of `@source` (which should be `@sources` to match conventions BTW) inside the form?

Comment: i'm new to rails so i'm just picking up pieces here and there. so i'm guessing @sources itself within the controller would give me the entire list, and thus no need for a form_for?

Comment: the form_for @source is actually going to include more than the one drop down going forward